# single table inheritance in ember-data v1.0.0

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm migrating an ember application from ember-data **v0.13** to **v1.0.0** .

In version v0.13, `RESTSerializer` used to have a materialize callback that allowed me to map rails STI models to ember models.

So when I get a list of events with different types, i would convert each of them to the appropriate ember model

```
"events": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "cash_inflow_event",
        "time": "2012-05-31T00:00:00-03:00",
        "value": 30000
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "asset_bought_event",
        "asset_id": 119,
        "time": "2012-08-16T00:00:00-03:00",
        "quantity": 100
    }
]
```

Ember models

```
App.Event = DS.Model.extend({...})
App.AssetBoughtEventMixin = Em.Mixin.create({...})
App.AssetBoughtEvent = App.Event.extend(App.AssetBoughtEventMixin)
App.CashInflowEventMixin = Em.Mixin.create({...})
App.CashInflowEvent = App.Event.extend(App.CashInflowEventMixin)
```

Ember-data code v0.13 that created the STI-like ember models

```
App.RESTSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    materialize:function (record, serialized, prematerialized) {
        var type = serialized.type;
        if (type) {
            var mixin = App.get(type.classify() + 'Mixin');
            var klass = App.get(type.classify());
            record.constructor = klass;
            record.reopen(mixin);
        }
        this._super(record, serialized, prematerialized);
    },

    rootForType:function (type) {
        if (type.__super__.constructor == DS.Model) {
            return this._super(type);
        }
        else {
            return this._super(type.__super__.constructor);
        }
    }
});
```

How can I do the same thing in ember-data **v1.0.0** ?

Answer (score 2):

I think I've got a solution...

There's a setupData callback on models.
I did the following

```
App.Event = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    setupData:function (data, partial) {
        var type = data.type;
        if (type) {
            var mixin = App.get(type.classify() + 'Mixin');
            this.reopen(mixin);
        }
        delete data.type;
        this._super(data, partial);
    },
    eachAttribute: function() {
        if(this.get('type')){
          var constructor = App.get(this.get('type').classify());
          constructor.eachAttribute.apply(constructor, arguments);
        }
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
     }
});
```

**Ember experts, is this a good idea??**

Comment: Great question and answer. This feature would be extremely useful, not only for rails users. Did this solution work for you? I'm having some problems with relationships. The relationships defined in the mixins are null.

Comment: For my purposes it did work!! I don't think the solution is "100% clean" however. It might introduce undesirable behaviors since it seems to violate some assumptions ember data makes. @miguelcobain , Could you post an example of what's not working for you ?

Comment: It's very simple to explain. Basically everything that is defined on the mixin doesn't get "normalized". Property names are still underscored from the api, relationships still not processed (only an id). I believe that this solution bypasses Embar Data's importante pipelines.
Honestly, I tried everything but didn't manage to get it. Then I came up with this proposal: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/proposal-class-centered-polymorphism/3457

Comment: @miguelcobain I edited the answer.. It now delegates the eachAttribute function to the type contructor. See if that works. I think it gets closer to a clean solution, but still is not.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. eachAttribute is never called thereby resulting in attributes of the mixin not being normalized.

Answer (score 1):

First, since you are using Rails, you may want to use the ActiveModelAdapter & extend your custom serializer from its serializer:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter;
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({...});
```

It looks like your custom serializer should override `typeForRoot` & probably `normalize`. Here is what those methods looks like now:

`DS.ActiveModelSerializer#typeForRoot`:

```
typeForRoot: function(root) {
  var camelized = Ember.String.camelize(root);
  return Ember.String.singularize(camelized);
}
```

`DS.JSONSerializer#normalize`:

```
normalize: function(type, hash) {
  if (!hash) { return hash; }

  this.applyTransforms(type, hash);
  return hash;
}
```

Comment: I played around with the normalize callbacks, but wasn't able to get what i want (STI-like inheritance with ember models). The intent of the normalize callbacks seems to be cleaning up JSON data to make it fit what ember-data expects.

Comment: @tartek correct. I was hoping you could move away from the mixins and custom code, but I guess you want the array of mixed event types to come back as one array of events? In that case, I think you are probably on the right track with the mixins.